# como agregar libreria mail en mavejava

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;

import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import usuario.registro;
```

no puedo agregar la libreria mail en mi proyecto con maven  y java me da errores y despues no encuentra la libreria

Comment: Hola! ¿Qué error te muestra al agregarla?

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente deberás de añadir el jar donde buscar las dependecias.
Según el gestor de dependecias que tengas se hace de un modo u otro.

```
Para maven, sería añadir esto en la sección dependencies:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Si no, puedes añadir el jar de javax.mail manualmente al build path

Comment: mil gracias, lo hice y me funciono, te agradezco ya que estoy comenzando.

Comment: Me alegro mucho de que te haya funcionado. ¿La puedes marcar como respuesta correcta? Gracias.